# Vertical alignment of reaction mechanism

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

How can I align the following reaction mechanism of the Aspirin synthesis in chemfig?

Code:

```
\schemestart
\definesubmol\nobond{-[2,0.2,,,draw=none]}
\chembelow[5mm]{\chemfig[][scale=0.7]{HO-[:-30]@{5}(!\nobond\scriptstyle\oplus)(-[:-90]CH_3)(-[@{2}:30]O-[:-30](-[:-90]CH_3)=[:30]O)}}{\chembelow[5mm]{+}{\chemfig[][scale=0.7]{*6(=-=(-([:90]=O)([:-40]-OH))-(-@{4}O@{3}H)=-)}}}
\qquad\qquad
\arrow(.base east--.base west){->[\tiny\chemfig{{-}CH_3COOH}][][4pt]}
\chemfig[][scale=0.7]{*6(=-=(-([:90]=O)([:-40]-OH))-(-O-[:-210](-[:90]@{7}O-[@{6}:360]H)(-[:210]CH_3))=-)}
\chemmove[->,shorten <=2pt]{
    \draw[shorten >=8pt](2)..controls +(-50:2.5cm)and+(45:1cm)..(3);}
\chemmove[->,shorten <=2pt]{
    \draw[shorten >=3pt](4)..controls +(180:1cm)and+(-135:1cm)..(5);}
\chemmove[->,shorten <=2pt]{
    \draw[shorten >=5pt](6)..controls +(90:5mm)and+(90:5mm)..(7);}
\arrow{->[\tiny\chemfig{{-}\chemabove{H}\oplus}]}
\chemfig[][scale=0.7]{*6(=-=(-([:90]=O)([:-40]-OH))-(-O-[:-210](=[:90]O)(-[:210]CH_3))=-)}
\schemestop
```

Thank you for your answer!

[image: Reaction mechanism in the actual state]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. How do you want them to align exactly?

Comment: Thanks four your comment. Sorry for the inconvenience, I'll add this in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\definesubmol\nobond{-[2,0.2,,,draw=none]}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
  \subscheme[-90]{
    \chemfig[atom style={scale=0.7}]{
      HO-[:-30]@{5}(!\nobond\scriptstyle\oplus)(-[:-90]CH_3)(-[@{2}:30]O
      -[:-30](-[:-90]CH_3)=[:30]O)
    }
    \arrow{0[+][][-10pt]}
    \chemfig[atom style={scale=0.7}]{*6(=-=(-([:90]=O)([:-40]-OH))-(-@{4}O@{3}H)=-)}
  }
  \arrow{->[\tiny\chemfig{{-}CH_3COOH}]}[,1.5]
  \chemfig[atom style={scale=0.7}]{
    *6(=-=(-([:90]=O)([:-40]-OH))-(-O-[:-210](-[:90]@{7}O-[@{6}:360]H)(-[:210]CH_3))=-)
  }
  \arrow{->[\tiny\chemfig{{-}\chemabove{H}\oplus}]}
  \chemfig[atom style={scale=0.7}]{
    *6(=-=(-([:90]=O)([:-40]-OH))-(-O-[:-210](=[:90]O)(-[:210]CH_3))=-)
  }
\schemestop
\chemmove[->,shorten <=2pt]{
  \draw[shorten >=8pt](2)..controls +(-50:2.5cm)and+(45:1cm)..(3);
  \draw[shorten >=3pt](4)..controls +(180:1cm)and+(-135:1cm)..(5);
  \draw[shorten >=5pt](6)..controls +(90:5mm)and+(90:5mm)..(7);
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Despite the scaling and the `\tiny` fontsize for the arrow labels the scheme stil exceeds the page width. Personally I'd play with `chemfig`'s `atom sep` (and `bond offset`) but choose a larger fontsize, `\footnotesize` maybe. (In the example below `showframe` visualizes the page dimensions.)

The example uses the `chemmacros` package (which also loads the `chemformula` package). It provides the `\scrp` and offers the possibility to print all charges in `chemformula`'s formulas (`\ch`) as formal charges (`\chemsetup{ charges/circled = all }`)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemfig,chemmacros,showframe}
\definesubmol\pchargeup{-[2,0.4,,,draw=none]\scrp}
\definesubmol\pchargedown{-[6,0.4,,,draw=none]\scrp}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \chemsetup{charges/circled=all}
  \setchemfig{atom sep = 1.7em , bond offset = 0.5pt}
  \footnotesize
\schemestart
  \subscheme[-90]{
    \chemfig{
      HO-[:-30]@{C1}(!\pchargeup)
      (-[:-90]CH_3)
      (-[@{b}:30]O-[:-30](-[:-90]CH_3)=[:30]O)
    }
    \arrow{0[+][][-10pt]}
    \chemfig{*6(=-=(-([:90]=O)([:-40]-OH))-(-@{OH}OH)=-)}
  }
  \arrow{->[${}-\ch{CH3COOH}$]}[,1.7]
  \chemfig{
    *6(
      =-=(-([:90]=O)([:-40]-OH))
      -(-O-[:-210]@{C2}(-[:90]O-[@{H}:360]H)(!\pchargedown)-[:210]CH_3)
      =-
    )
  }
  \arrow{->[${}-\ch{H+}$]}
  \chemfig{*6(=-=(-([:90]=O)([:-40]-OH))-(-O-[:-210](=[:90]O)(-[:210]CH_3))=-)}
\schemestop
\chemmove[red,-el,shorten <=2pt,shorten >=2pt]{
  \draw[shorten >=8pt] (b) ..controls +(-50:2.5cm) and +(10:1cm)  .. (OH) ;
  \draw (OH)..controls +(180:1cm)   and +(-135:1cm).. (C1) ;
  \draw (H) ..controls +(-90:3mm)   and +(30:5mm)  .. (C2) ;
}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this extremely useful code. I'm totally new in LaTeX (playing around with it for 2 days now) and so I could learn much from your code. But there are still some minor questions: 
1. What does "\chemsetup[option]{circled=all}" do? 
2. Is it possible to make this vertical alignment without centring the reaction scheme horizontally?
3. What are the parameters of this: "\arrow{->[${}-\ch{CH3COOH}$]}[,1.7]" and what do they do?

Again, thank you very much!

Comment: 1.) `\chemsetup` is the setup command for the `chemmacros´ package. The `circled` option determines how the charges are printed. 2.) I don't understand the question.  For the rest I'll add something to my answer tomorrow.

Comment: @Sam an arrow `\arrow{->}` with label `${}-\ch{CH3COOH}$` (this is math like `$a-b$` but with an empty atom before the minus and a `chemformula` after it) scaled to 170% of its normal length `[,1.7]`: `\arrow{->[${}-\ch{CH3COOH}$]}[,1.7]`